Can't sync with network
We have a solochain testnet running with a lot of users. Our nodes managed by us yet. Some blocks ago the nodes stopped producing new blocks, because of a crash in a pallet. The pallet was from substrate's frame and as the chain is live, we forked the pallet, patched it and upgraded the nodes (deployed new nodes on top of the old chain). We didn't increase any number in RuntimeVersion and we used old chainspec json file with new nodes, without introducing codeSubstitutes or something. The nodes started producing new blocks. From that point we couldn't connect updated nodes to the network and the only way was connect the old "unpatched" version, wait until chain synced to the block caused the problem and updating the node to the "patched" version to sync the rest of the blocks.
Now we upgraded the runtime using setCode and new nodes can connect to the network and they are syncing 4799 blocks (4795 is the latest finalized) out of about 500 000. It's not the block which caused the issue previously with "unpatched" nodes, but after this block syncing node shows errors like:
2024-07-02 14:09:36  Error importing block 0xb7fe2f7e1bf5bc0dcb6c889d95fa2f06f33f8612bfa206b1129de38c7120eaf2: consensus error: Import failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution faile
d: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x4da9a6 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x42d01e - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h30eb0b0c070928e2
    2: 0x3f03ec - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::execute_block::h6fbe71b3f2a20da4
    3: 0x41ec8d - <unknown>!Core_execute_block    

The question is too generic, but what can we do now to actually being able to run new nodes and sync from scratch just by connecting to the network?
UPD
the actual error is Digest item must match that calculated:
2024-07-11 14:37:18 [4695]  new validator set of size 3 has been processed for era 8    
2024-07-11 14:37:18 panicked at /Users/*/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/ec7817e/substrate/frame/executive/src/lib.rs:671:13:
Digest item must match that calculated.    

